# How to find permutations of specific sets of data

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

As said in the title I have this set of data:

`A1 A2 A3
 B1 B2 B3 B4
 C1 C2
 D1 D2 D3 D4 D5`

I want to find all permutations of combinations like so:

`A1 B3 C2 D5`
or
`A2 B1 C1 D5`

etc..

I am trying to do this programmatically and can't find a formula for something like this.

Comment: just say permutations instead of permutations of combinations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about this with just A1, A2, and B1, B2, and B3.

The following are the 6 ways to arrange them:

1. A1, B1
2. A1, B2
3. A1, B3
4. A2, B1
5. A2, B2
6. A2, B3

Therefore, there are $2*3=6$ ways to arrange them. Now, think about the big picture, as in your question. 3 A terms, 4 B terms, 2 C terms, and 5 D terms. What do you do with them?

**Spoiler:**

> $3*4*2*5=120$ ways to arrange the set of data

This is also known as the **Fundamental Counting Principle**.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is combinations of

- one entry from $3$ possiblities listed on the A list,
- one entry from $4$ possibilities listed on the B list,
- one from the $2$ possibilities listed on the  C list, and
- one from $5$ possibilities listed on the D-list.

Using rule of the product: That gives us $3 \times 4\times 2 \times 5 = 120$ possible combinations.

Note, this is precisely what we get when computing $$\binom 31 \cdot \binom 41 \cdot \binom 21 \cdot \binom 51 = 120$$

---

Now, if you consider, say, $(1) \;(A_1, B_2, C_2, D_3)$ one such choice, you need to decide whether, say, $(D_3, B_2, A_1, C_2)$, which is merely a rearrangement (permutation) of $(1)$ counts as different.  If so, you need to multiply $120$ by $4! = 24\;$ to get all permutations of all combinations possible: $120 \times 24$.